# Unable to call function via companion object

Tags: java, scala

Why in in the below example, can I not call x.callMe(). My understanding is that assigning "var x = Test" would return a new instance of Test and invoking callMe on it should be the same as invoking y.callMe()

```
class Test{
   def callMe() = println("called")
}

object Test{
   def apply() = new Test()
}


var y = new Test()
y.callMe()

var x = Test
x.callMe()
```

Comment: var x = Test. You are just assigning the type. Use var x = Test().callMe                           //> called

Comment: To be clear: `var x = Test` just makes `x` a reference to the companion object. As others have said, you can do `var x = Test()`; or, you could do `x().callMe()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the method you are trying to call is not a member of the companion, use:

```
val x = Test()
x.callMe()
```

to invoke the `apply` you defined that will return an instance of the `Test` class that you can call `callMe` on.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, use Scala console.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Test{
   def callMe() = println("called")
}

object Test{
   def apply() = new Test()
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Test
defined object Test
```

Now let's see what happens when you call `new Test()`.

```
scala> var y = new Test()
y: Test = Test@722c41f4
```

The type of the `y` variable is `Test`. So clearly we can call `callMe()` method.

```
scala> y.callMe()
called
```

When you execute the second snippet:

```
scala> var x = Test
x: Test.type = Test$@4b6995df
```

Note the type is `Test.type`. This is just a reference to `Test` object. You can call it like `x()`, which invokes `apply()` method and gives you new `Test` object each time.

```
scala> x()
res2: Test = Test@3f0ee7cb

scala> x()
res3: Test = Test@60f82f98
```

You can also, which I believe is you wanted to do in the first place, call `Test()`, which will invoke the `apply()` method on the `Test` object.